# I have joined two tables. I'm trying to group by the city and it doesn't group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have joined two tables. I'm trying to group by the city and it doesn't group by.

Please look at the query below and suggest where I'm going wrong.

```
SELECT city, sales, Profit
FROM obd
INNER JOIN orders 
ON orders.OID = obd.OID
GROUP BY sales, Profit, City
ORDER BY city
```

Here is the output for the above query:
[image]

I want to group the results by city to be not redundant by summing up the sales and profits.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551  and sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT city, SUM(sales), SUM(Profit) 
 FROM obd AS BD 
 INNER JOIN orders AS ORD ON ORD.OID = BD.OID 
 GROUP BY City 
 ORDER BY city
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple things on this one. You might want to sum the sales and profit columns if you want to group the results by city, that way you get your totals and it can give you an easily readable report. Something like:

```
SELECT city, SUM(sales) as [Sales Total], SUM(Profit) as [Profit]
 FROM obd AS BD 
 INNER JOIN orders AS ORD ON ORD.OID = BD.OID 
 GROUP BY city 
 ORDER BY city
```

If you want to order by sales or profit, you could change the ORDER BY clause and it will order your results accordingly. (If you wanted to report your top sales, change the last line to: ORDER BY [Sales Total] DESC).